# How to add data in SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to add a single integer value into my SQLite database. The problem is that the int value is in another class, how do I add that one value into my database where it says total wins? i just want to add that one piece of data inside?

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public Database(Context applicationContext) {
    super(applicationContext, "HighScores.db",null, 1);
}

@Override //creating database
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    String query = "CREATE TABLE HighScores (totalWins INTEGER)";
    database.execSQL(query);
}

@Override //if the table exists then drop it
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int arg1, int arg2) {
    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HighScores";
    database.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(database);

}

//for inserting values
public void insertHighScores(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("totalWins",queryValues.get("totalWins"));

    database.insert("HighScores", null, values);
    database.close();
}

//for updating values
public int updateHighScores(HashMap<String, String> queryValues){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("totalWins",queryValues.get("totalWins"));

    return database.update("HighScores", values, "totalWins" + " =?", new String[] 
            {queryValues.get("totalWins")});
}
//return all highscores
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>getAllHighScores() { 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> highScoreArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM HighScores";

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor MyCursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (MyCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do{
            HashMap<String, String>highScoresMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            highScoresMap.put("totalWins",MyCursor.getString(0));

            highScoreArrayList.add(highScoresMap);

        }while(MyCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return highScoreArrayList;
}

   }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message when you try to insert?

Comment: I dont know how to insert I have not tried inserting because I dont know how, why is there something wrong with the database?

Comment: Have you read this? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Android Developer is no help

Comment: you don't explain your problem well and don't post the second class that contain the value you want to add its value , be more clear so we can help you

Comment: Second class has just an int value.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
public class SomeOtherClass{


Database  myDatabase = new Database (this);

public void editHighScores(int myvalue){

    HashMap<String, String> queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
    queryValues.put("totalWins", myvalue);

    myDatabase.insertHighScores(queryValues);
}
}
```

Comment: but this is storing an edit text? I have a int value in another its not in an activity and I am trying to store that int value into the database.